# Determining the character styling for every character in RICHT TEXT EDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, rich-text-editor

I have gone through many such topics on Stackoverflow and thanks to it that I am able to build my **small rich text editor**.

However, when you put your **mouse cursor on character which is already bold or styled before** then I cannot find a way to identify the styling. What I would like to see is that, if the mouse cursor is put where the text is bold then automatically highlight bold symbol (kind of a javascript or jquery solution). Most of the rich text editor has this feature and would just like to know idea behind this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in C#. I hope it's useful to you.

```
private void rtb_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rtb.SelectionFont != null)
    {
        btnBold.Checked = rtb.SelectionFont.Bold;
        btnItalic.Checked = rtb.SelectionFont.Italic;
        btnUnderline.Checked = rtb.SelectionFont.Underline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer. I have implemented my richtext using HTML and jquery. Will definitely try to use this concept there. Lets see how it goes. Thanks again for your reply :)